# ImageMagick changing replacing a color on palette using C#

Tags: c#, imagemagick, color-palette, magick.net

I have a bitmap image generated by a third party software that only allows use of the basic 16 colours.

I need to change the pure yellow RGB(255, 255, 0) to a slightly darker shade, so when printed we can see there is data there RGB(255, 192, 0).

I found the Mogrify command, but that is used in the command prompt, and I need to use an equivalent of this as method in C#.

Many thanks in advance :D

Comment: I did a similar thing using the **AForge.Imaging** library, maybe it could be a simpler alternative, here's all you need to get it working: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/67fa83b5-dede-8d3a-8d3b-b7a6b9859538.htm and http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/35bd90e3-4e35-8f5f-e255-26c5d8d4b927.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is assuming that your image has an indexed color palette.  You can edit the palette of a .BMP file (or an indexed .PNG) using System.Drawing objects.  The code would look like this:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
...
using (var bmp = (Bitmap)(Image.FromFile("input.bmp")))
{
    var paletteCopy = bmp.Palette;

    // palette index 11 is bright yellow in the standard palette
    paletteCopy.Entries[11] = Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 0);
    bmp.Palette = paletteCopy;
    bmp.Save("output.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```